# About PCA in R?

Tags: r, pca

I used caret package in R to preprocess data like :

```
> trans <- preProcess(data, method  = "pca").
> transformedData <- predict(trans, data)
```

Here's my problem, after that the predictors' name on original data was missed, but a list of PCs. How can I find the relationship between those PCs with my original predictors, u know , there're some loadings or coefficients on those predictors.

Could some one gives me a hint, better use caret methods. Thanks!

Comment: what is it you're asking? What are pc's? have you looked at biplots and how much variation each pc explains?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really familiar with caret, but couldn't you use [princomp](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/princomp) or [prcomp](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/prcomp.html)?

For example:

```
# some random data
x   <-data.frame(a=1:25+rnorm(25),
                 b=3:27+rnorm(25,mean=1), 
                 c=25:1 + rnorm(25,mean=2,sd=2))
pca <- prcomp(x, retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
transformedData <- pca$x
loadings        <- pca$rotation
eigenvalues     <- pca$sdev
```

Also see this resource on ["5 functions to do Principal Components Analysis in R"](http://gastonsanchez.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/principal-components-analysis-in-r-part-1/).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I understood your question 100%, but I am guessing you have a dataset with missing names, and you want to quickly identify the relation(linear maybe) between variables, identify the 'Principle Components'?

Here is a very awesome [`cross validated` post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76906/how-can-i-interpret-what-i-get-out-of-pca) showing you some knowledge of the PCA and SVD.

And here is a very simple example showing you how it works using `prcomp` function:

```
>library(ggplot2)
>data(mpg)
>data <- mpg[,c("displ", "year", "cyl", "cty", "hwy")]
# get the numeric columns only for this easy demo
>prcomp(data, scale=TRUE)

Standard deviations:
  [1] 1.8758132 1.0069712 0.5971261 0.2658375 0.2002613

Rotation:
  PC1         PC2        PC3         PC4         PC5
displ  0.49818034 -0.07540283  0.4897111  0.70386376 -0.10435326
year   0.06047629 -0.98055060 -0.1846807 -0.01604536  0.02233245
cyl    0.49820578 -0.04868461  0.5028416 -0.68062021  0.18255766
cty   -0.50575849 -0.09911736  0.4348234  0.15195854  0.72264881
hwy   -0.49412379 -0.14366800  0.5330619 -0.13410105 -0.65807527
```

Here is how you interpret the result:

(1) The standard deviations, which is the diagonal matrix in the middle when you apply the singular value decomposition. Explains how much variance each 'Principle Component'? / layer / transparency explains in the whole variance in the matrix. 
For example,

```
70 % = 1.8758132^2 / (1.8758132^2 + 1.0069712^2 + 0.5971261^2 + 0.2658375^2 + 0.2002613^2)
```

Which indicates the first column itself already explains 70% of the variance in the whole matrix.

(2) Now let's look at the first column in the rotation matrix / V:

```
          PC1       
displ  0.49818034 
year   0.06047629
cyl    0.49820578
cty   -0.50575849
hwy   -0.49412379
```

***We can see: `displ` has a positive relation with `cyl` and negative relation with `cty` and `hwy`. And in this dominant layer, `year` is not that obvious.***

The makes sense, the more displacement or cylinders you have in your car, it probably has a very high MPG.

Here is the plot between the variables just for you information.

```
pairs(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to look at the `rotation` variable of the resulting list:

```
> trans <- preProcess(data, method  = "pca").
> transformedData <- predict(trans, data)
> trans$rotation
```

And if you want to look at a specific PC, say the two first ones:

```
> trans$rotation[,c(1,2)]
```